# How to pass boolean values in HttpParams in post http request typescript/angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm new to angular7/typescript i want to pass boolean value as a Httpparam, Is it possible ?

```
let body = new HttpParams();
body = body.set('name', string);
body = body.set('value', boolean);
```

Issue is how do i pass boolean value

Comment: its a valid question, i wonder why there are downvotes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would help to know what you are trying to do.  However, you could do this:

```
    body.set('paramStringName', booleanValueYouWantToPass.toString());
```